# Is it right to use desktop/laptop UX patterns for touch based devices?

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, design-patterns, touch-screen

I've noticed recently that we often use UI elements and UX patterns from desktop and laptop, which often stem from the primary input device being a mouse or physical keyboard.

We then apply these to touch screen devices such as tablets, assuming will understand them because they will be familiar with a desktop/laptop experience.

However I see more and more articles saying that a lot of users are skipping the desktop/laptop world.

- [Tablets drive increase in older people going online](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/news/10795257/Tablets-drive-increase-in-older-people-going-online.html)
- [One in three children now has their own tablet computer](http://media.ofcom.org.uk/news/2014/media-lit-audit-oct2014/)
- [Emerging shifts - away from PCs](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2014/jun/13/pc-market-doldrums-will-continue-to-2018-says-idc)

Should we be considering taking interface cues from the physical world instead of older generations of computers?

Answer (score 1):

> Should we be considering taking interface cues from the physical world instead of older generations of computers?

I think this question is setting up a false premise that it's one or the other. I'd argue it's likely neither.

The best practice these day is to consider 'mobile first' to accommodate the very real fact that more and more people are using mobile devices to interact with the internet. That means we shouldn't be bringing over mouse-centric thinking of the desktop. As for real physical world, that's always been an option and always will be. But I'd argue that what what we really should be doing is focusing on: creating UIs and interactions that leverage touch.